# Javascript function always calls the .asp method from the else clause

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm writing a web page in ASP.NET. I have a sessionTimer JavaScript function with one "if/else" conditional clause. It retrieves variable from the config file by calling an asp.net function in the if clause and then in the else clause calls another ASP.net function to do some other things. This code always calling the .asp function in the else loop. Can you please tell me why?

```
var sessionTimeout = 1;
function Timerfunction()
{
     sessionTimeout = sessionTimeout - 1;
     var sessiontimoutValue = '<%= GetSessionTimeout() %>';

     if (sessionTimeout >= 0) {    
         window.setTimeout("Timerfunction()", sessiontimoutValue);
     }
     else {
         var result = '<%= Timer_Timedout() %>'
     }
}
```

Comment: Using server side injection means that the client side logic is not evaluated, it is literally using that method to write the string to the response, so it will be called every time

Comment: Where is the call to invoke `Timerfunction` and what is the value of `sessionTimeout` at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Using `<%= %>` tags to inject values from the server is literally adding that value,in this case, the results of the function `Timer_Timedout()`, into the response that is sent to the client.

This means that anything inside those tags will be evaluated regardless of the client side logic in the javascript so it can be included in the response.  It will not go back to the server to get those values, they are included literally within the quotes on the initial response from the server, meaning the function will execute any time that page is requested.

You are likely needing to perform some kind of ajax or additional request to get the session status from the server based on the logic you define on the client.